# The width of the row for HTML table is not displayed as expected when sent as an email using SMTP client

Tags: c#, html, css, email

I am using a HTML code with css styling and sending it as an email body using SMTP. But in the email, the width of the rows are more than it is expected.The spacing between the rows are more.
I have also added

> 'IsBodyHtml = true'
>
> 'BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7'

Still nothing seems to work.
please suggest.
Below is the HTML code. Also attached is the screenshot of the email https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZbpJ.png-:

```html
Hello Team,
This needs your input. 
<HTML>
<DIV>
<TABLE BORDER ="1" WIDTH = 1000 >
<TR>
 <TH align ="left" bgcolor="#D3D3D3"><H3><B>Test Details</H3></TH>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<Div>
<table align="left" width=100%>
<TR bgcolor="#D3D3D3">
<TD class="ColumnBorder" align="right"></TD>
<TD class="ColumnBorder" align="right">Test1</TD>
<TD class="ColumnBorder" align="right">Test2</TD>
<TD class="ColumnBorder" align="right">Price</TD>
</TR>
 <TR  class="RowBorder">
      <TD align="left" BGCOLOR="#99B4D1" width="25%">Price1</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="D8E6FE" align="right" width="25%">27,082.16</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right" width="25%">64.23</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right" width="25%">49,167.00</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR class="RowBorder">
      <TD align="left" BGCOLOR="#99B4D1" width="25%">Price2</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right" width="25%">10.00</TD> 
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right" width="25%">20.00</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right" width="25%">30.00</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE align="left" style = "border-width:1px" width=100%>   
   <TR>
      <TD align="left" BGCOLOR="#99B4D1" width="25%">Price Testing TTTTTT xxxxxxx</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#FFC000" align="right" width="25%">Value1</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#99B4D1" align="right" width="25%">Some Value2</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right" width="25%"></TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD align="left" BGCOLOR="#99B4D1" width="25%">The final Status</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right" width="25%">Success</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#99B4D1" align="right" width="25%">The Previous Status</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right" width="25%">Failed</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#99B4D1">This is the Correct Version</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right">1</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#99B4D1" align="right">2</TD>
      <TD BGCOLOR="#D8E6FE" align="right">3</TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>
</Div>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD><TABLE  width = "100%">
      <TH colspan = "5" bgcolor ="#D3D3D3"><B>The main Price</B></TH>
      <TR bgcolor ="#D3D3D3">
      <TD align="left">Description</TD>
      <TD align="right">Final Price(>=)</TD>
      <TD align="right">Min Discount</TD>
      <TD align="right">Days</TD>
      <TD align="right">Max Discount</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR bgcolor = #00B050 style="display:@Testing1">
      <TD align="left">Testing1</TD>
      <TD align="right">34,267.81</TD>
      <TD align="right">59.52</TD>
      <TD align="right">NA</TD>
      <TD align="right">N/A</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR bgcolor = #00B050 style="display:@Testing2">
      <TD align="left">Testing2</TD>
      <TD align="right">99,210.81</TD>
      <TD align="right">97.52</TD>
      <TD align="right">NA</TD>
      <TD align="right">N/A</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR bgcolor = #CCFFCC style="display:@Testing3">
      <TD align="left">Testing3</TD>
      <TD align="right">59,190.81</TD>
      <TD align="right">57.52</TD>
      <TD align="right">NA</TD>
      <TD align="right">N/A</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR bgcolor = #CCFFCC style="display:@Testing4">
      <TD align="left">Testing4</TD>
      <TD align="right">79,270.51</TD>
      <TD align="right">59.52</TD>
      <TD align="right">NA</TD>
      <TD align="right">N/A</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR bgcolor = #FFFF99 style="display:@Testing5">
      <TD align="left">Testing5</TD>
      <TD align="right">98,141.30</TD>
      <TD align="right">59.98</TD>
      <TD align="right">NA</TD>
      <TD align="right">N/A</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR bgcolor = #FFFF99 style="display:@Testing6">
      <TD align="left">Testing6</TD>
      <TD align="right">10,011.80</TD>
      <TD align="right">61.23</TD>
      <TD align="right">NA</TD>
      <TD align="right">N/A</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR bgcolor = #FF0000 style="display:@Testing7">
      <TD align="left">Testing7</TD>
      <TD align="right">30.00</TD>
      <TD align="right">190</TD>
      <TD align="right">NA</TD>
      <TD align="right">N/A</TD>
      </TR>      
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>
<STYLE Type ="text/css">
table{border-collapse:collapse}
td{
font-family: Microsoft Sans Serif;
font-size:8.25pt;
}
th{
font-family: Microsoft Sans Serif;
font-size:8.25pt;
width:13em;}
tr{
height:2em}
.RowBorder{border-bottom:none;border-top:none}
.ColumnBorder{border-Right-width:1px}
</STYLE>
</HTML><br/>Disclaimer: This is for reference only.<br/>
<br/>This is just for testing purpose.<br/>
```

Comment: Try with valid HTML...

Comment: The entire thing goes as mail body and it is valid HTML. I need help with the formatting of HTML code.Please ignore the rest.

Comment: However email client will consider whole bunch of text as HTML, it will not ignore this and that. Also _inner_ HTML isn't valid. Check it with an online validator. I don't know if this is the reason or not (I usually just ignore invalid HTML) but you may want to try with a simple table and add parts until it fails...